# Hard disk space not getting free

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, uninstall

I had installed a few programs like UDK and Microsoft Visual Studio. Both acquired at least 20GB of space. After uninstalling these programs, the free space of Harddisk hasn't increased. What is going on , why the space hasn't been freed?

Kindly guide me. I am on Windows 7

Comment: Try Disk Cleanup and a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. But still I will take a go at it . When you install visual studio it comes with the core software and its dependencies . The core studio software only takes around 2 gb of the alloted space , while they rest is taken by the dependencies(libraries and framework) and not to forget the updates .

Solution :

1. One solution is to use softwares like **revo uninstaller** to uninstall the software and the dependencies.
2. use this link to manually remove all the dependencies . [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/98dfa323-323d-4ecd-a955-fd0014dec92e/). follow the steps which are given and you will remove all of them .

tip: if you still are not seeing free space , possible reason is that your disk is highly fragmented.Please use a [defragmenters](http://lifehacker.com/5854427/five-best-disk-defragmentation-tools)